# Error 500 after website uploading (no .htaccess, no WP)

Tags: php, apache, syntax-error, error-log

I just went to upload the 1st version of a new project I built on the host. To be clear, everything were ready to start working but finally all I got was :

> HTTP ERROR 500

I know [what does this mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#500).

My project is **100% handmade with PHP**, no WP or other CMS/platform, and there is **no Apache file** (.htaccess will be added later).
But there is a ***error_log*** file, which always have the same line :

```
[19-Jan-2017 12:59:06 America/Chicago]
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$sgbd' (T_VARIABLE)
in /path/to/the/file.php on line 1
```

It refers to my database connexion file :

```
<?php
$sgbd = "mysql";
$host = "localhost";
$database = "dont_worry";
$charset = "utf8";
$user = "this_is_not";
$password = "my_infos";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
];
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('' . $sgbd . ':host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database . ';',
'' . $user . '', '' . $password . '', $options);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

This is the 1st file called by my pages, right after `session_start();`. I really don't get what can be wrong.
I was not prepared to this, thanks for helping !

**EDIT :** I "solved" the problem, but don't know how it happened. The file was automatically modified on upload, deleting the space between the begining of the PHP code and my first variable :

```
1 | <?php$sgbd = "mysql";
```

I verified this file and modified it many times to try to find a solution. The only way was to delete and re-upload the complete project.

Comment: You may have an older version of PHP. If you have command line access to your server run `php --version` otherwise, add a `phpinfo();exit;` in the first line of your code to see the version number and send it to us.

Comment: @Ibu I don't have command line access, but there is a cPanel which allows me to choose the PHP version. After verifying I am on PHP 7.1

Comment: When you don't know where to start tracking down an error, start troubleshooting from scratch.  Remove all files from your WWW root and see if you still get the error.  Create a blank `index.php` file and see if you still get the error.  Put `<?php echo "hello"; ?>` within your `index.php` file and see if you still get the error.... etc., keep building it back up until you see the error.... you should get the idea... some basic troubleshooting.  Alternatively, you can do the same process in reverse, methodically stripping out code until the 500 error clears.

Comment: thanks @Sparky , I'll try that if I have no other solution. I checked the post you linked and don't find anything at the moment

Comment: Basic troubleshooting... it should be your first resort, not your last.  I mean, we have absolutely nothing here... any answers would be blind guesses, so the responsibility falls to you to get the basic troubleshooting done before we can even begin to help.

Comment: @Sparky I supposed there was something simple I was missing (as the server part is mostly unknown to me). Anyway I hope to find the reason soon and will edit at this moment.

Answer (score 3):

There's no syntax error in the quoted source with the exception that if you are running this code on PHP 5.3 or earlier, then this:

```
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
];
```

will cause syntax error as this [short array syntax is available since 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

Aside from the above, the following line:

```
$bdd = new PDO('' . $sgbd . ':host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database . ';',
               '' . $user . '', '' . $password . '', $options);
```

is over-engeneered. There's absolutely no point of doing `''` you typed a lot as this simply equals to **empty** string. Second row also shows that you got problem understanding the difference between **variable** and **variable's value**. This should be easily written as:

```
$bdd = new PDO("{$sgbd}:host={$host};dbname={$database};", $user, $password, $options);
```

Aside from the above it should not be the cause of 500 you are facing.

**EDIT**

If you can invoke PHP from command line (on most linuxes it comes as separate package (i.e. `php-cli` so you may need to install it first)), then you can check the syntax of your file using `-l` switch:

```
$ php -l file.php
```

if there's any issue, then you will see the error message. If you see just `Errors parsing file.php` but no details, add `-d error_reporting=E_ALL` to the argument list:

```
$ php -d error_reporting=E_ALL -l file.php
```

Alternatively, you can simply try to access your file directly in browser (if it is not in document root, just copy it to make it available - it does not matter calling it alone makes no sense - you just need to ensure you are looking at right file - if you do, then syntax error will be logged. If this is wrong file, then nothing should happen really.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the `PDO` line, that's how I learnt and didn't change it.
After improving this line, and verifying my **PHP version (7.1)**, still **ERROR 500**. Maybe I'm showing useless information but as I don't know where does it comes from

Comment: And you are still seeing seeing the same syntax error message in error log?

Comment: Yes, still the same.

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: Okay thanks ! It's a bit late here, I'll come back to you as soon as I solve this